# Call a function depending on checkboxes instead of select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a newbie in JS/JQuery and I am trying to replace an old code with a new one.

I have a select list that contains a lot of items. This list allows to add the selected item to a hidden input.

This is the prototype of the function:

```
<select id="selectAptitudes" onchange="$('aptitudes_id').value=this.value; addAptitudeField(this,'aptitudes');">
```

and this is the hidden input:

```
<input name="aptitudes_id" id="aptitudes_id" type="hidden" value="">
```

And this is the particular function that is ruining my life:

```
addAptitudeField : function(currentAutocompleteField, idChamp) {
    // Allows to send param to setTimeout
    var currentAutocompleteFieldBind = currentAutocompleteField;
    var idChampBind = idChamp;
    // setTimeOut allows to execute the function
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        var idChamp = idChampBind;
        var currentAutocompleteField = $(currentAutocompleteFieldBind);
            var currentValue = currentAutocompleteField.options[currentAutocompleteField.selectedIndex].title;
            var currentCategorie = currentAutocompleteField.options[currentAutocompleteField.selectedIndex].parentNode.label;
            var currentParent = currentAutocompleteField.parentNode;
            var allInputs = currentParent.getElementsByTagName("input");
            var countAllInputs = allInputs.length;
            var lastAutocompleteFieldId = allInputs[countAllInputs - 1];
            var lastValueId = "";
            if (lastAutocompleteFieldId != null) {
                lastValueId = lastAutocompleteFieldId.value;
            }

            /* A lot of instructions to add elements to database using Ajax
            * and to write added elements in the end of the page
            */

            if ( $('selectAptitudes')){
                $('selectAptitudes').options[0].selected = true;
            }

            $(idChamp + "_id").value = "";
            }
        }, 400);
    },
```

Well, the problem that I want to resolve is that this way allows us to select one item by time, that's why I replaced the select by checkboxes (easy to check/uncheck), and I added a button.

What I'm looking for is one time I click on the button, I can execute the same instructions : `"$('aptitudes_id').value=this.value; addAptitudeField(this,'aptitudes');` for every checked element.

My idea is to call a function that creats a list of checked boxes, and every item of this liste call the first function. I tried with this small code but it doesn't work.

this is my function:

```
ajouterApt = function(){
    var listApt = [];
    $('.Aptitudes input:checked').each(function() {
        listApt.push(this.name);
    });
    nbrItem = listApt.length;
    for(var i=0; i<nbrItem; i++){
        $('aptitudes_id').value=listApt[i].value; 
        addAptitudeField(listApt[i],'aptitudes');
    }
};
```

I think that my function needs something to call correctly the function "addAptitudeField()".

Thank you in advence for your time and help

Comment: Use `$('#aptitudes_id').val(this.value)` instead of `$('aptitudes_id').value=this.value`. For ID selector you need to prefix `#` with ID

Comment: @Satpal Thank you for your reply, but nothing changes, I don't know why the page reuploads when I click on the button.

Comment: *"I don't know why the page reuploads when I click on the button"* - Is the button in a form? Is it a submit button or a `<button>` element with no `type` attribute?

Comment: @nnnnnn there is no form just like this:
`<button id="ajouterDesAptitudes" onclick="ajouterAptitudes()" disabled>Ajouter</button>` inside a div